# Cambiar id y recogerlo como elemento

Tags: javascript

Tengo un programa en el que cambio el ID de un botón constantemente, el problema es que necesito acceder a dicho botón, y al cambiarle el ID dejo de poder acceder a él, ya que no existe un elemento con el ID "button", cómo podría solucionarlo?

```js
var getUser = "user";
var getPassword = "password";

let position = 1;
let div = document.getElementById("div");

function button_Hover() {
    let last = position;

    do {
        position = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 3);
    } while (position == last);

    let validPassword = document.getElementById("password").value == getPassword;
    if (!validPassword) {
        let posStr = "";

        if (position === 0) {
            posStr = "left";
        } else if (position === 1) {
            posStr = "center";
        } else {
            posStr = "right";
        }

        div.style.textAlign = posStr;
    }
}

setInterval(start, (1 / 30) * 1000);
function start() {
    let button = document.getElementById("button");
    let password = document.getElementById("password");

    if (password.value != getPassword) {
        button[0].id = "button";
    } else {
        button[0].id = "buttonOk";
    }
}
```

```css
#root {
    align-items: center;
}

#button {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: none;
    width: 33%;
    height: 4vh;
    border-radius: .5em;
    font-size: large;
}

#buttonOk {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: none;
    width: 33%;
    height: 4vh;
    border-radius: .5em;
    font-size: large;
}

#buttonOk:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.input {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    width: 50%;
    height: 4vh;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

#div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input" placeholder="Usuario"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input" placeholder="Contraseña"><br>
    <div class="input" id="div">
        <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="button" class="button" onmouseenter="button_Hover()">
    </div>
</div>
```

para hacer el cambio de id poner en el input Contraseña "password"

El programa a simple vista funciona bien, el problema es que al poner la contraseña, pasar el mouse por encima, cambiar la contraseña para que esté mal, y volver a pasar el raton por encima, sigues pudiendo dar click al boton sin que este se desplace, y al debuggear me he dado cuenta de que es porque no es capaz de acceder a una ID que no existe, ya que se cambió.

Comment: Hola GreenLass, realmente creo que la pegunta que te tienes que hacer es: "tiene algún sentido cambiarle el *id*?", creo poder aventurar que la respuesta es no, te diría que con cambiar el texto que muestra es más que suficiente, aunque no puedo estar totalmente seguro.

Comment: Y por qué no lo manejas con una clase?

Comment: Tal y como te ha dicho @MarcePuente, los identificadores deberían ser únicos e inamovibles. Lo que estás haciendo es, permíteme ser sincero, una aberración. Si deseas tener siempre localizado a un elemento, su `id` es lo único que deberías usar para ello ya que, teóricamente, no va a cambiar nunca (ejem). Si lo usas para almacenar datos en su lugar se [usan los atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), pero si lo usas para cambiar el estilo de un botón.. ¡ooh! ¿he dicho estilos? para eso debes agregar o quitar clases al elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empecemos recordándote que las siguientes construcciones son completamente innecesarias:

```
let div = document.getElementById("div");
```

Siempre que un elemento tenga un identificador, el navegador crea un atributo en el ámbito global (`window`) con dicho nombre, por lo que podrás acceder al elemento usando cualquiera de las siguientes maneras:

```
console.log(div); // siempre que estemos en el ámbito `window`
console.log(window.div);
console.log(window["div"]);
```

Para continuar, un identificador debería ser único e inamovible (no puede cambiar).

El uso que le das al identificador es para cambiar el estilo (aspecto) de un botón, pero para eso se usan las clases, no los identificadores.

Cuando se crea un estilo CSS que hace referencia a un identificador (algo que empieza por `#`) estás indicando que afectará únicamente a un elemento y no a un conjunto de ellos.

Para terminar, puedes hacer lo que deseas haciendo uso de [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) (que tienen su selector CSS) o bien agregando o quitando una clase o, por último, cambiando la clase completamente.

Aquí te muestro un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo cambiando el cambio a la clase.

```js
var getUser = "user";
var getPassword = "password";

let position = 1;

function button_Hover() {
    let last = position;

    do {
        position = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 3);
    } while (position == last);

    if (password.value != getPassword) {
        let posStr = "";

        if (position === 0) {
            posStr = "left";
        } else if (position === 1) {
            posStr = "center";
        } else {
            posStr = "right";
        }

        div.style.textAlign = posStr;
    }
}

setInterval(start, (1 / 30) * 1000);
function start() {
    if (password.value != getPassword) {
        button.class = "button";
    } else {
        button.class = "buttonOk";
    }
}
```

```css
#root {
    align-items: center;
}

#button {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: none;
    width: 33%;
    height: 4vh;
    border-radius: .5em;
    font-size: large;
}

#button.buttonOk {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: none;
    width: 33%;
    height: 4vh;
    border-radius: .5em;
    font-size: large;
}

#button.buttonOk:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.input {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    width: 50%;
    height: 4vh;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

#div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input" placeholder="Usuario"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input" placeholder="Contraseña"><br>
    <div class="input" id="div">
        <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="button" class="button" onmouseenter="button_Hover()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, no entiendo cuál es la necesidad de cambiarle el id a un botón constantemente, existen diferentes formas de lograr lo que tratas.

Volviendo a la pregunta, puedes tratar de acceder al botón mediante la clase o por el tipo de etiqueta. Mira el siguiente código:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('boton_clase')
//También:
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2]
```

Recuerda que usamos `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2]` de esa forma ya que el método retorna un arreglo de nodos `input` y el primer elemento está en la posición `0` el tercero está en el índice 2.